# Android Lollipop SDcard Permission

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-permissions

I am developing an application which which uses permission of `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, I am using this line to delete files from sdcard:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
```

When I use this intent it ask for some permission to give to external storage again and again, but I don't want to do this.

Comment: You don't want to do what?